# python strip function gives unexpected result

Tags: python, string, strip

I want to strip the substring `'_pf'` from a list of strings. It is working for most of them, but not where there is a `p` in the part of the string I want to remain.  e.g.

```
In: x = 'tcp_pf'
In: x.strip('_pf')
Out: 
'tc'
```

I would expect the sequence above to give an output of `'tcp'`

Why doesn't it? Have i misunderstood the `strip` function?

Comment: Carefully read the manual for the `strip` method: "If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on"

Comment: Have you tried consulting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)? "The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped"

Comment: OK, I thought it would only strip the whole substring passed to it, rather than any of the characters within it. Is there an alternative function that does what I am trtying to do?

Comment: You're right @Peter  it's a duplicate. I should have looked harder. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
x = 'tcp_ip'
x.split('_ip')[0]
```

Output:

```
'tcp'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use spilt function like below,

x.split('_pf')[0]

It will give you tcp.